# Dojo build module dependencies

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to use the Dojo builder to build a single file which includes all modules my application needs, but without the application itself.

Here an example layer definition.

```
layers: {
    'dojo/dojo': {
        include: [
            'myApp/main'
        ],

        boot: true,
        customBase: true
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, with this definition the builder looks at the modules used in main.js and combines them into one file with my main.js.

What I'm trying to archive is to create this single file without main.js.

That means I only what one file with all the Dojo modules my application is depending on.

Have you any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your config is already creating the file you're looking for - it's just called `dojo/dojo.js`.

You'll see this in your config - that's what the layer name is for.  Right now, you're creating a layer called `dojo/dojo.js`, which is a customBase boot layer, and includes `myApp/main` and all its dependencies.

**EDIT**

Apologies, I read "without the main.js" as "without Dojo's main.js".

Unfortunately you've stumbled on a limitation of the build scripts - they can't "include dependencies, but exclude modules matching X".

In this case, your only solution will be to manually list your application's dependencies in your layer.

If you're running a development web server, you could consider adding some alerting to dojo/ dojox/ dijit/ etc. to help you identify modules you're missing from the configuration.

Comment: the thing is, I don't want myApp/main included. only its dependencies